# modal verb 'have to'

Tags: modal-verbs

Do we use *have to* to express a strong probability? Are these sentences correct:

- This suit can’t really cost $200.  This has to be a misprint. (to refer to the present possibility)
- Food prices have to go down sooner or later. (to refer to the future possibility)
- No one else could have taken my wallet – it had to be Sam.(to refer to the past possibility)

*Have got to* is more informal; is it possible to use it to refer to the past? (*had got to*)?

Comment: I don't think we use *"had got to"* for the past. I have no idea if there's any grammatical reason why we can't.

Comment: @Peter: Perhaps you needed Mark Twain (in Huck Finn) [to show it had got to be done](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22to+show+how+it+had+got+to+be+done%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1)

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. Please note that questions which can be answered by checking a dictionary are off-topic here. See ODO— *[have](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/have): 3.2 Be certain or inevitable to happen or be the case*— and the note there on *have got* as well.

Comment: @Fumble: Don't forget that *Huckleberry Finn* is written in the voice and dialect of an illiterate Missouri native of about 11 years old c. 1846. So I wouldn't recommend it as a model for grammarians.

Comment: @Robusto: I certainly wouldn't forget that! I just made [much the same point](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/63383/the-usage-of-get-to-ing#comment121372_63383) in respect of another question (on ELL) citing Mark Twain. Many such usages are still "valid", but often they were never exactly "standard".

Comment: @PeterShor: We use *must have been* instead, so the reason is not a grammatical one.

Answer (score 0):

> •This suit can’t really cost $200. This has to be a misprint. 
>   •Food prices have to go down sooner or later. 
>   •No one else could have taken my wallet – it had to be Sam

I don't think the speakers are expressing a degree of probability. I think they are expressing inevitability.

> Have got to is more informal; is it possible to use it to refer to the
>   past? (had got to)?

More informal than what? This statement doesn't refer to anything earlier in the question. I think we need an actual example.